# Google Compute Engine VM, Added Load Balancer now can't git pull

Tags: git, ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a google compute engine that I set up a git repo on and everything was going great and I was git pulling with zero problems. Then, I set up a load balancer and a created an NEG for my VM and was able to get https running. But, now when I run git pull it does nothing. It just hangs there with no output, even if I use `-v` it has no output and just hangs indefinitely. I don't even know if the load balancer and https set up is related, but I can't think of anything else. I already tried regenerating SSH keys with no effect. Any ideas?

This is my git remove -v output:

```
origin  git@github.com:LukasDeco/thoughtful.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:LukasDeco/thoughtful.git (push)
```

and git status:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   .gitignore
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

## **UPDATE:**

For git fetch origin, this is the output I get from the timeout:

```
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Then I tried to use https and this is the output:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/LukasDeco/thoughtful.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

It seems like a network issue, but I have the default-allow-ssh firewall rule on my VM so port 22 should be open.

Comment: 1) Why did you create a NEG? The Google Load Balancers do not need that for Compute Engine. 2) What is the network configuration for Compute Engine? 3) Verify that you can connect from Compute Engine to the Internet and to github.com (identity possible routing problems). 4) Your question is not clear, add more details.

Comment: 1) It makes me either use an NEG or an instance group and I only want to use one instance whereas an instance group I think makes me use multiple instances. 2) I am on an internal IP for compute engine. Is that what you mean? 3) When I run ping on the compute engine it says 0 packets received everytime.... 4) Basically I want git pull to work again

Comment: 1) Google offers Unmanaged Instance Groups. 2) If your Compute Engine instance does not have a public IP address, then you will need a Cloud NAT (or similar) to provide public Internet access. There are other options, but Cloud NAT is the simplest.

Comment: Once I added the NAT it worked again!! Thanks so much

Comment: Don't forget to select VonC's answer to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by [John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley) in the comments, and detailed in "[Compue Engines / Securely connecting to VM instances / Traffic egress using NAT gateways](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely#natgateway)"

> When an instance does not have an external IP address assigned it cannot make direct connections to external services, including other Google Cloud services.
>
> To allow these instances to reach services on the public internet, you can set up and configure a [NAT gateway machine](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs), which can route traffic on behalf of any instance on the network
>
> Cloud NAT is a distributed, software-defined managed service.
> It's not based on proxy VMs or appliances.
>
> Cloud NAT configures the [Andromeda software](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2014/04/enter-andromeda-zone-google-cloud-platforms-latest-networking-stack.html) that powers your VPC network so that it also provides **source network address translation (SNAT)** for VMs without external IP addresses.
> Cloud NAT also provides **destination network address translation (DNAT)** for established inbound response packets.
>
> [image: Traditional NAT vs. Cloud NAT -- https://cloud.google.com/nat/images/07.svg]